# Is it possible to use a specific method of an object (or a static method) as a functor in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, functor, functional-interface

I am trying to understand functional interfaces in Java 8. Suppose f() to the functor:

```
public class A {
    private double a;

    public A(double a_) {
        a = a_;
    }

    public void f(double[] b, double[] c, double[] d) {
        d[0] = a * (b[0] + c[0]);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to create a similar construction using the Java 8 functional interface ?

```
public class B {
    public double g(Function funct, double[] b, double[] c, double[] d) {
        funct(b, c, d); //Call the functor, minor calculations
        return d[0];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A(1);
        double[] b = {2};
        double[] c = {3};
        double[] d = {4};
        double res = g(a.f, b, c, d);
    }
}
```

In other word,is it possible to use a specific method of the object (or a static method) as a functor? If so, could you give a short example?

The functor represent an illustration of the function working with a data member (a) and some additional parameters (b, c, d )...

Comment: It looks like you just want `a::f` as a method reference, but you've only provided pseudocode at the moment which makes it harder to help you.

Comment: @ Jon : The pseudocode is used because I do not know the correct syntax :-)

Comment: `funct` is instance, so you can't use it like `funct(a,b,c)` but you may want to use it like `funct.calculate(a,b,c)`. You should probably store/return result of such method. Anyway to be able to invoke `calculate` on three arguments you would need to have functional interface with method which could accept such arguments. So you would need something like `interface ThreeArrayFunction{ double calculate(double[] a, double[] b, double[] c);}`.

Comment: @ Pshemo: Could I ask you for the example? My primary language is C... Thanks...

Comment: Just because you don't know the syntax for *that* part doesn't mean you can't get the rest right. You should be able to write a program which is entirely correct apart from the *one* part you don't know about. Your initial code had broken variable declarations.

Comment: @ Jon: Thank you for pointed this out.... Some edits were made...I am doing several things together and forgot to fix the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution. Initially, the interface IFunction is created:

```
public interface IFunction {
   double eval(double [] a, double [] b, double [] c) ;
}
```

The class A remains:

```
 public class A {
    private double a;

    public A(double a_) {a = a_;}

    public void f(double[] b, double[] c, double[] d) {
        d[0] = a * (b[0] + c[0]);
    }
 }
```

However, the class B uses a function pointer:

```
public class B {

  public double g(IFunction funct, double[] b, double[] c, double[] d) {
    funct.eval(b, c, d);
    return d[0];
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     A a = new A(1);
     double[] b = {2};
     double[] c = {3};
     double[] d = {4};

     double res = g(a::f, b,c, d);
 }
```

I hope it helps... Maybe,there is a better solution :-)

Comment: I don't understand the relationship between class A and the IFunction interface.  Do mean for A to implement IFunction interface, renaming method 'f' to 'eval'?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use the existing java 8 interfaces.

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.function.Function;
import org.junit.Test;

public class test {

  @Test
  public void java_functions_currying() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    A a = new A(1);
    Double[] b = {2d};
    Double[] c = {3d};
    Double[] d = {4d};
    double res = B.g(a::f, b, c, d);
    double res1 = B.g1(a::f1, b, c, d);

    assertEquals(5, res, .01d);
    assertEquals(5, res1, .01d);
  }

  public class A {
    private double a;

    public A(double a) {
      this.a = a;
    }

    // f has type Function<Double[], BiConsumer<Double[], Double[]>>
    // Function<T, R> where 
    // T = Double[]
    // R = BiConsumer<Double[], Double[]>
    public BiConsumer<Double[], Double[]> f(Double[] b) {
      return (c, d) -> d[0] = a * (b[0] + c[0]);
    }

    // f1 has type Function<Double[], Function<Double[], Consumer<Double[]>>>
    // Function<T, R> where 
    // T = Double[]
    // R = Function<Double[], Consumer<Double[]>>
    public Function<Double[], Consumer<Double[]>> f1(Double[] b) {
      return c -> d -> d[0] = a * (b[0] + c[0]);
    }

  }

  public static class B {
    public static double g(Function<Double[], BiConsumer<Double[], Double[]>> funct, Double[] b, Double[] c, Double[] d) {
      funct.apply(b).accept(c, d);
      return d[0];
    }

    public static double g1(Function<Double[], Function<Double[], Consumer<Double[]>>> funct, Double[] b, Double[] c, Double[] d) {
      funct.apply(b).apply(c).accept(d);
      return d[0];
    }
  }
}
```

The method f returns void, therefore the use of Consumer class is appropriate.
A Consumer takes a parameter but does not return.

I have added two solutions. The first one uses a BiConsumer which accepts two parameters.

Java 8 does not provide a TriFunction or TriConsumer interface, but this is not needed. Actually even the BiFunction and BiConsumer interfaces are not needed, they can be created through the Function and Consumer interfaces.

```
BiFunction<T, U, R>      <=> Function<T Function<U, R>>
BiConsumer<T, U>         <=> Function<T, Consumer<U>
TriFunction<S, T, U, R>  <=> Function<S, Function<T, Function<T, R>>>
TriConsumer<S, T, U>     <=> Function<S, Function<T, Consumer<U>>>
```

[Search for currying](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=currying%20computer%20science) to get more information about functions which always only take one parameter but return functions to get the still missing parameters.

Comment: @ mrt181 Thanks for the sent solution. As a C++ programmer, I am slightly surprised, how the Java syntax  may be complicated :-).